# High CPU usage after Raspi Upgrade

Tags: cpu, update

Not sure if is related to the version upgrade but since I have updated my Raspberry to Linux version 4.1.13+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140303 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2650 - Linaro GCC 2014.03) ) I can see a high percentage of CPU usage. (See graph)

[image]

I tried to check munin graphs but I does not give me a clear understanding of what is going on. There is any way to see the history of the CPU process? I want try to understand wich process is doing that. From top command everything seems ok (but top command gives just real time process)

Comment: Wow, from the graph it does not appear that there was a reboot - I wonder if some old process is churning away or if maybe the CPU is the result of memory swapping issues perhaps.

Comment: The pooling of data has done every 5 minutes. How can I understand if some old process are creating the problem?
Thanks

Comment: rebooting might help clear the problem. You don't mention what distro/version you are using, but I see this kind of CPU usage when opening too many tabs on Ubuntu mate.

Comment: I did reboot more than once but the situation is the same. The 
RASPBIAN WHEEZY, the version you can find in the descriptin

Answer (score 2):

Found it: the same day I installed munin and that is the root problem:the pooling of the data requiring high CPU